# Sinatra JSON response looks accurate in WEBrick but doesn't work in Passenger/Apache

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra, passenger, webrick

So I have a small piece of Ruby/Sinatra code that returns a JSON as the response. The code works and the result is accurate in WEBrick, but in my Passenger/Apache setup the message is blank for the same code. Here is my code and response from WEBrick and Passenger/apache

Here is my code

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  before do
    content_type :json
  end
  post "/" do
    payload = JSON.parse(request.body.read, :symbolize_names => true)
    raw = payload[:pem]
    pem = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new raw    
    File.open("cert.cer", "wb") { |f| f.print pem }
    message = %x[ruby ../do-something.rb cert.cer]
    {subject: sub_CN, message: message, success: "1" }.to_json
  end
```

And the output when this is run in WEBrick is

```
{
"subject": "mail.google.com",
"message": "This certificate is good\tcurrently valid.\nIt appears the cert 
 will expire in\t2 months.\n",
"success": "1"
 }
```

And the output from Passenger/Apache is

```
{
    "subject": "mail.google.com",
    "message": "",
    "success": "1"
}
```

please keep in mind the message contains \t and \n. Do these mess with Apache or Passenger?

Comment: Passenger seems to use another `ruby` and `%x[ruby ../do-something.rb cert.cer]` returns unpredictable results. Start with debugging `%x[which ruby]` or like under Passenger.

Comment: Good point, however I checked that already and don't think it is the issue. In fact the environments use different Ruby version, but the code does work as anticipated in both and when outputting to the console.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to a ruby script? Why not require the ruby code and run it directly?

Comment: The long answer is, do-something.rb is an external code that is cloned and used. It includes four different folders in -I during run time and the class/modules are all over the place within these folders. While it is not a hassle to require (require_relative) the various modules including among-st each other, the folks who will be using this don't want to go through that each time there is a new commit. Right now I have $LOAD_PATH in the do-something.rb to include the four folders, but using directly is something that is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the behavior you're seeing is most likely because the command `%x[ruby ../do-something.rb cert.cer]` failed for some reason. If it failed then it *should* have printed something to stderr, which ends up in [the global Apache log file](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/log_file/). Please look in that file and check whether you can find the relevant error messages.